# Wouldn't a simple scalar field fix the non-renormalizability of gravity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity, partition-function, ghosts

It is well known that [quadratic gravity is renormalizable](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235472686_Renormalization_of_Higher_Derivative_Quantum_Gravity). On the other hand it is possible to transform the partition function of Einstein-Hilbert + free minimally coupled complex scalar field into a theory of quadratic gravity-type as follow:

In $(+,-,-,-)$ signature the action proposed is$^1$:
\begin{equation}
S=-\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}\left( \frac{1}{2\kappa}R + \phi^\ast(\square_g+m^2)\phi \right) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
The generative functional is then (if we assume some kind of sum over geometries):
\begin{align}
Z[J,K] &= \int \mathcal{D}g\mathcal{D}\phi^\ast\mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{iS+i\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left(J^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu\nu}+K^\ast \phi+K\phi^\ast\right)}
\\
&=\int \mathcal{D}g\,[\det(\square_g+m^2)]^{-1}e^{-\frac{i}{2\kappa}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} R}e^{i\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} J^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu\nu}}\underbrace{e^{i\int d^4 x \int d^4y \sqrt{-g_x} \sqrt{-g_y}K^\ast_x G_{xy}K_y}}_{\equiv z_\phi[K^\ast,K]}
\\
&=\int \mathcal{D}g\,e^{iS_\text{quad}}z_\phi[K^\ast,K]e^{i\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} J^{\mu \nu}g_{\mu\nu}} \tag{2}
\end{align}
Where we used the [heat kernel method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138) to finally have:
\begin{equation}
S_\text{quad}=-\left( \frac{1}{2}m^4+\left[\frac{1}{6}m^2 +\frac{1}{2\kappa} \right]R+\frac{1}{72}R^2-\frac{1}{180}R_{\mu \nu}R^{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{180}R_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}R^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}+\frac{1}{30}\square_g R \right)\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Since the renormalizability of the quadratic gravity theory does not depend on the signs of the coefficients, this theory is renormalizable. Sure there are ghosts but since the theory is effective, it should not impact too much the underlying physics. In particular, the equations of motion of the theory seem to indicate a possible minimum non-zero position uncertainty physically acceptable if the mass $m$ is of the order of the Planck mass.

So my question is: Does the previous development make sense at all? In particular, does this approach have been explored before? I think it is the case because it is quite simple but the fact that I don't see it on the internet tends to indicate to me that there's a flaw in the reasoning...

---

$^1$ Free vector fields and fermionic fields lead to similar results, in the case of a fermionic field one should express the spin connection with the tetrads.

Comment: You are just saying that integrating out degrees of freedom produces an effective action which includes higher-dimension operators. That's fine. But I don't think this by itself fixes any problems. For example, the conclusions section of the referenced paper begins "The renormalizable models which we have considered in this paper should be regarded as constructs for a study of the ultraviolet problem of quantum gravity. The difficulties with unitarity appear to preclude their direct acceptability as
physical theories..."

Comment: (I cannot comment as to whether your action really terminates at quadratic terms -- sounds fishy to me.)