# How can a boundary have an equation of motion? (Quadratic gravity with boundaries)

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions, action, boundary-terms

This question is the following of [my previous one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/686084/) on the appearance of quadratic gravity from a simple scalar field treated non-perturbatively. In the following, I will not specify the $\epsilon$ term indicating if the boundary is space-like or time-like.

I was interested in the case where space-time can have boundaries, and the contribution of the Klein-Gordon's determinant (with mass $m$) in the case of Dirichlet boundary condition is:
\begin{align}
    S=&\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_{\mathcal{M}}d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left[ -\frac{1}{6} m^2 R+\frac{1}{2}m^4+\frac{1}{30}\square R+\frac{1}{72}R^2+\frac{1}{120}C^2-\frac{1}{360}G \right]
\nonumber \\
    &+\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}d^3x \sqrt{\gamma}\left[ -\frac{1}{20}\partial_\textbf{n} R+\frac{1}{15}\square K-\frac{1}{3}m^2 K+\frac{1}{18}RK+\frac{1}{90}KR_{\textbf{n}\textbf{n}}-\frac{1}{30}R^\alpha_{\textbf{n} \beta \textbf{n}}K^\beta_\alpha+\frac{1}{90}R_{\mu \nu} K^{\mu \nu} \right.
\nonumber \\
    &\left. +\frac{1}{189}K^3-\frac{11}{315}K K_{\mu \nu} K^{\mu \nu}+\frac{8}{189}K^\beta_\alpha K^\gamma_\beta K^\alpha_\gamma  \right]
\end{align}
Where $T_\textbf{n} \equiv n^\mu T_\mu$, $n^\mu$ is the normal of the boundary, $K_{\mu \nu}$ is the extrinsic curvature, $C^2$ and $G$ are respectively the Weyl quadratic and the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet density, and $\gamma$ is the induced metric. After some manipulation to extract the boundary terms of $R^2$, $C^2$ and $G$ from the integral over $\partial \mathcal{M}$, I arrive at:
\begin{align}
    S=&\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_{\mathcal{M}}d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left[ -\frac{1}{6} m^2 R+\frac{1}{2}m^4+\frac{1}{72}R^2+\frac{1}{120}C^2 \right]+B_{\text{GHY}}^{m^2}+B_{R^2}+B_{C^2}-\frac{1}{180}\chi(\mathcal{M})
\nonumber \\
    &+\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}d^3x \sqrt{\gamma}\left[ -\frac{1}{60}\partial_\textbf{n} R+ \frac{1}{90}KR+\frac{2}{45}KR_{\textbf{n} \textbf{n}}-\frac{1}{90}K^{\mu \nu}R_{\textbf{n} \mu \textbf{n} \nu}+\frac{1}{15}K^{\mu \nu}R_{\mu \nu} \right.
\nonumber \\
    &\left.+\frac{4}{315}K^3-\frac{2}{35}K K_{\mu \nu}K^{\mu \nu}+\frac{26}{945}K^\beta_\alpha K^\gamma_\beta K^\alpha_\gamma  \right]
\end{align}
The $B$ terms are these boundary terms and $\chi(\mathcal{M})$ is the Euler characteristic of the space with its boundaries. So far... not so good because the integral over $\partial \mathcal{M}$ does not vanish. In fact its variation is expressed with $\partial_\alpha \delta g_{\beta \gamma}$. So I have two equations of motion from $S$: one from $\delta g_{\beta \gamma}$ in the bulk and one from $\partial_\alpha \delta g_{\beta \gamma}$ on the boundary.

My question since I've never seen that in the past: Is it OK to have an additionary equation of motion that restricts the possibilities of the dynamics of the boundary in the context of General Relativity?

More precisely: Since these equations of motion are (in my case) the ones of the space-time at a high energy scale (the Planck mass' energy scale), does it mean that, in this context, in the quantum realm the space-time's boundaries have certain dynamics?